# How to add array values in a string in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Can anybody please tell me how to put `array values[Adding Values]` into a `string` or `integer`.

Suppose an array `a=[1,2,3]`.

After Adding(+ Action) it should be like

```
string=1+2+3=>6
```

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 4):

Use **KVC Collection Operator**

```
NSArray *array =@[@(1),@(2),@(3)];
NSLog(@"Sum is : %@", [array valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop over your string array and sum it up?!

```
NSArray *array = @[@"1", @"2", @"3"];

NSInteger sum = 0;
for (NSString *string in array) {
    sum += [string integerValue];
}
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)sum);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..Its perfect Ans…

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *array  = @[@1, @2, @3];  

int sum = 0;    

for (NSNumber * number in array)
{
   sum += [number intValue];
}

NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use KVC..

```
NSNumber *num1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
NSNumber *num2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
NSNumber *num3 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];

NSArray *arr1= @[num1, num2, num3];
NSString *str = [arr1 valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.intValue"];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
NSArray *array  = @[@1, @2, @3];
NSInteger sumArray = [[array valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.integerValue"] integerValue];
```

**I converted the final value to integer, if you don't need then you can replace it by:*

```
NSString *sumArray = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.integerValue"];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's overkill to use NSArray. 
Use plain C array.

```
int myArray[] = {1,2,3};
int i = 0; int sum= 0;

for (i=0; i < 3; i++){
    sum += myArray[i];
}
char str[15];
sprintf(str, "%d", sum);
printf("%s", str);
```